How do I specify tmux terminal-features in my config like I do with "-T"?
I'm looking for how to modify my tmux config such that they "hyperlink" feature is enabled by default.
Motivation
I'm attempting to make my tmux config work with hyperlinks. I'm running on Ubuntu 24.04 and in a default terminal I can run:
 python3 -c "if 1:
     import rich
     import pathlib
     dpath = pathlib.Path('~').expanduser()
     rich.print(f'[link={dpath}]{dpath}[/link]')
 "

(above requires Python3 and pip install rich)
Which will print a link that I can control+click to open up a nautilus window to that directory. However, by default if I open a tmux session and type the same command it will print with nice colors, but it will not be control clickable.
I've done a bit of searching on this topic and found a thread:
file hyperlink not working under tmux
Which claims hyperlink support was added in version 3.4, which is what I'm using.
A Partial Solution
After a bit more searching it turns out that hyperlink support does indeed exist in the version I'm running, but it doesn't seem to be enabled by default. However, I've found a method that enables it. If I start my tmux session with :
tmux -T hyperlinks

And run the above code, it will print a link I can click! Furthermore, there is a nice test to see if the feature is enabled. If I run:
tmux display -p "#{client_termfeatures}"

The comma-separated string will contain "hyperlinks" if the feature is active. So great, this shows a proof-of-concept that the feature exists and can work. Now I need to enable it in my configuration, but this is causing me more trouble than I would have expected.
The Issue
The next thing I want to do is get this feature enabled by default without needing to specify the -T option on the command line. I could do this with an alias, but I'd rather set it in the tmux config, which seems like a cleaner way to do it. However, I'm having trouble getting it to work.
I've searched a bit in the FAQ for tmux which gives an example of adding something to terminal features:
set -as terminal-features ",gnome*:RGB"

So the first thing I tried was adding the link
set -as terminal-features "hyperlinks"

However, when I start a new session and try the tmux display -p "#{client_termfeatures}" or just attempt to print a hyperlink with rich it does not work.  I've tried running tmux source ~/.tmux.conf to ensure the config was reloaded and I've also tried to manually run the command with ctrl+b :<command>. I've also tried variants with the -g flag, but none of these have gotten me a working hyperlink.
The main question:
How do I correctly add "hyperlinks" to the terminal-features array in my ~/.tmux.conf file?

In a shell inside tmux invoke
tmux show-option -s terminal-features

In my case the above command prints:
terminal-features[0] xterm*:clipboard:ccolour:cstyle:focus:title
terminal-features[1] screen*:title
terminal-features[2] rxvt*:ignorefkeys

The first entry means that if my $TERM when starting a tmux client matches xterm* (e.g. it's xterm-256color) then inside tmux the command tmux display -p "#{client_termfeatures}" will print a comma-separated string containing (but not necessarily limited to) entries clipboard,ccolour,cstyle,focus and title.
If I want to add hyperlinks to this array, I need to invoke
tmux set -as terminal-features 'xterm*:hyperlinks'

Then I have to detach the client (prefixD, where prefix is by default Ctrl+B) and attach anew (tmux a). Then tmux display -p "#{client_termfeatures}" will include hyperlinks.
In ~/.tmux.conf the line will be:
set -as terminal-features 'xterm*:hyperlinks'

In practice this method does not give me the hyperlink support because my setup without tmux does not support hyperlinks anyway. I understand you've got it covered, so the method should work for you. But you need to adjust the line to $TERM your tmux client will see. E.g. if your $TERM outside tmux is gnome-256color then use gnome* instead of xterm*.
You can even use * instead of xterm* to make tmux enable hyperlinks for any value of $TERM seen by the client. It will be like using -T hyperlinks unconditionally. I'm not sure what can go wrong if you enable the feature in tmux when the terminal of the tmux client does not support it. Settings things up in a way that only enables hyperlinks when hyperlinks are really supported seems neater.

Works like a charm
